# iOS return bad value for window.innerHeight/Width

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios

I'm using *window.innerHeight* and *window.innerWidth* instructions to get the browser's available window size.  It's working with firefox, safari (on a mac) and android but I get strange results in iOS.

iOS always returns innerHeight=1091 and innerWidth=980.

I'm using iOS emulator from the iOS SDK (I don't own an iPhone/iPod).  The same value is returned with the iPhone and iPhone Retina emulator.  I don't understand how they can both returns the same numbers because the 2 models have 2 different screens resolutions.

I played with the viewport parameter with no success.

Answer (score 35):

**TL;DR:** Use `document.documentElement.clientHeight/Width`

This is not exactly an answer to the question, but it's helpful information if you're trying to do things based on the size of the document shown in the browser.

`window.innerWidth` (and height) can get wacky on mobile browsers, even when you use the proper viewport meta tags. On some browsers it can be very inconsistent.

`screen.width` works better for mobile browsers, but then you need to take into account orientation and whether or not the browser is mobile or desktop (if you need to be responsive for both), as `screen.width` gives much more variation on desktop compared to `window.innerWidth`.

In my experience, `document.documentElement.clientWidth` is the best way to go. Mobile browsers are much more consistent for this attribute than for `window.innerWidth`, and since you're dealing with the dimensions of the html element and not the browser window or the device screen, it's consistent between mobile and desktop, and orientation does not need to be accounted for.

Answer (score 18):

Try to use `screen.width` instead of `window.innerWidth`.

```
<script>
  if (screen.width > 650) {
    ....
  }
</script>
```

Comment: One thing to note with this approach when writing cross-browser CSS, you want to remember the `screen.width` on the desktop is going to be high, as it will report the pixel width of the screen resolution on the OS itself, not the pixel width of the web browser window.

Answer (score 8):

Was stuck on the same issue. 
Here's the solution that worked for me.

First I'm detecting if the client is an iOS device. 
Then i'm getting correct values using [Screen interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen)

```
var iOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream; 
var iw = (iOS) ? screen.width : window.innerWidth, ih = (iOS) ? screen.height : window.innerHeight;
```

Comment: `window.innerWidth` will differ depending on orientation on iPhone.  You will need to look at `window.orientation` as well.

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no">
```

to the `<head>` element. That will fix the `innerWidth` issue.

The retina has high density pixels - basically 4 hardware pixels to 1 logical pixel. That's why they report the same resolution.

Comment: Did not help in my case... using Xcode 4.6.3 and iPhone 6.1 Simulator

Comment: `maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no` <= never do this. Disabling zoom is terrible practice for usability and accessibility

Comment: I had to put my check for `innerWidth` in a `setTimeout` for it to work. Even in a `window.onload` it gives me 980. I do have the meta tag. `screen.width` works right away.

Comment: Disabling zoom for your WEB APP (among other contexts) may be a perfectly good thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

`iOS` latest version does not support `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth`, because iOS will read the resolution.

So, you can use this :

```
screen.width
screen.height
```

I have try it in appetize.io emulator iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Check Apple's documentation on how to set the viewport for Mobile Safari, and how it scales: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

Basically, you can set a scale for the viewport, and make it default to whatever you want by setting a meta tag on your HTML page.

Comment: I found this page before posting here.  I was not completely sure this was related but I didn't find how to make safari mobile to not scale to 980x1091.  I tried with <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width"> but didn't changed anything.

Comment: If you want the viewport to be 320x480, you should try `<meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 1, user-scalable = no">`

Answer (score 1):

Also specify the height in the viewport meta tag according to this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />`

I had problems with using jQuery $(window).height() on my iPad 2 (5.0.1) since I had missed out specifying the height in the meta tag. After adding it works much better.

Comment: This will break if you have an iOS app that is not full screen.  It will make your webview full-screen size dimensions even if it is embedded only in the right pane of a split view.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue still. I have a full screen app, no need for user to scale anything (it's a kiosk), and solution for me was adding the `shrink-to-fit=no` meta.

My current meta for the viewport is:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no" />`

Now `window.innerWidth`, `jQuery(window).width()` and everything else related works properly.
Before that, I had to rotate iPad and return it back to original position for window size values to refresh to the proper ones.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is a known bug, but I spent my fair share of trial / error on this one. Apparently it takes a bit to update the window value and next event loop seems to be working correctly.

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  console.log(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight) // values before the resize / orientation change
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight) // values after the resize / orientation change
  }, 0)
})
```

Comment: After days of troubleshooting and hair pulling on an IOS bug where height and width data were used to locate a div element on a page, I came across this answer. Adding a short setTimeout around my code fixed it. Thanks!!