# Why does my website not display anything on mobile if I add this if statement?

Tags: javascript, mobile, resize, window

I have a [webpage](http://msolonko.net/spotit). I added an if statement that alerts a message if the window size is too small.

```
const WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
const HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
if(WIDTH<250 || HEIGHT<325){
    alert("Increase your window size and reload the page");
    function closeInstructions(){
        alert("Game is not playable at this resolution. Please reload the page once you have resized the window");
    }
}
else{
/*My main code here*/
    function closeInstructions(){
         instructionsClosed = true;
         instructions.style.display = "none";
         makeCards();//starts game
      }
}
```

function closeInstructions either alerts the user or starts the game. This all works well on a computer. If you open the link above, you can start playing given that your screen size is big enough. However, if you open that link on an iPad or iPhone, the canvas is not draw at all when the window width and height are large enough. If I just remove the two statements and don't worry about the window dimensions, everything works fine on computer and mobile. What is happening?

FYI: closeInstructions is called when the user clicks the "Ready" button.

Also, an error occurs if your screen is too small and you try changing the dropdown value but this has nothing to do with my issue. Everything still works on the computer. It does not, however, work on a full-sized iPad.

I tried on an emulated Android device, and it worked fine. Now I have no idea why it does not work on my phone and tablet.

EDIT
I found what works but I still can not understand why the code described above does not. This is what works:

```
const WIDTH = window.innerWidth-30;
const HEIGHT = window.innerHeight-30;
if(WIDTH<250 || HEIGHT<325){
    alert("Increase your window size and reload the page");
}
/*** MAIN CODE (Not in else statement)***/
function closeInstructions(){
    if(WIDTH<250 || HEIGHT<325){//checks condition
        alert("Increase your window size and reload the page");
    }
    else{//runs game if screen is big enough
         instructionsClosed = true;
         instructions.style.display = "none";
         makeCards();
    }
}
```

The above option works, but now just out of interest I would like to know why my previous method does not open on iPhone and iPad.

[Working version](http://msolonko.net/chinese)

[Non-working](http://msolonko.net/spotit)

**If you try [this](https://appetize.io/demo?device=iphone6s&scale=75&orientation=portrait&osVersion=11.1) random online iOS simulator, it does not work here.**

```
   const WIDTH = window.innerWidth-30;
   const HEIGHT = window.innerHeight-30;
   if(WIDTH<250 || HEIGHT<325){
    alert("Increase your window size and reload the page");
    function closeInstructions(){
        alert("Game is not playable at this resolution. Please reload the page once you have resized the window");
            }
    }
    else{
      const ITEMS_PER_CARD = 5;
      const SIZE = (ITEMS_PER_CARD<8)?Math.floor(Math.sqrt(HEIGHT/55*WIDTH)):Math.floor(Math.sqrt(HEIGHT/55*WIDTH)*8/ITEMS_PER_CARD);
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     function canvasStyle(){
        ctx.lineWidth=5;
        ctx.strokeStyle="#0000FF";  
        //ctx.font = SIZE*0.9+"px Times New Roman";
        ctx.textAlign="center"; 
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
      }
      makeCards = function(){
                canvasStyle();
                ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
      }
    function closeInstructions(){
         instructionsClosed = true;
         instructions.style.display = "none";
         makeCards();
      }
            }
```

I (somewhat) narrowed down the issue. In the above code, the square gets drawn on iOS **if I uncomment the ctx.font line** but does not if it is commented. In my complete game, if I do this, the borders are drawn, but the letters are still not.

Comment: How does it behave in a small browser window? Open Chrome (or whatever browser you use) devtools and try using screen sizes for different devices while watching the console logs.

Comment: Maybe try `screen.width` and `screen.height`?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629969/ios-return-bad-value-for-window-innerheight-width

Comment: @AdrianSmith it works well in Chrome will any screen size that is big enough and otherwise throws the alert.

Comment: @RickHitchcock I tried this and it still does not work on mobile but still works on a computer. Besides, I really need the innerWidth value and not screen width because my game needs to scale depending on the size of the open window.

Comment: I just tested this on my Google Pixel 1 running Android O and it's fine. Perhaps it's an issue with the browser you are using on your phone?

Comment: @AdrianSmith I just downloaded Chrome on my iPad and it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Your website is not responsive (scalable) to different resolutions or mobile friendly.

You need to add...

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1.0">
```

And perhaps...

```
 <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
```

Further down in your CSS replace...

```
 @media (max-width: 700px) {
```

With...

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
```

And finally, to get the user's viewport size use **offsetWidth** and **offsetHeight** instead of innerWidth and innerHeight.

Comment: I tried to use those changes but it did not resolve my issue.

Comment: Another quick observation... are you sure you can do width: 40%!important; without a space between the % and ! ? Hmm, I'm not sure about that...

Comment: Yes, I have done that for many projects and it has never caused any trouble.

Comment: Ok I'll take your word for it, well I don't have time to get into your logic further down so this is all I can offer you at a quick glance..

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this on an android device in chrome and it runs fine.

iOS devices are notorious for parsing the dom in unexpected ways. I would be really interested to see what values innerWidth and innerHeight are returning on iOS.

Honestly I would really expect something like this to work.

```
    var iOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
```

//check for iOS

```
var iw = (iOS) ? screen.width : window.innerWidth, ih = (iOS) ? screen.height : window.innerHeight;
```

//use screen.width instead

But in comments on the original post you say that screen.width doesn't work as well which isn't at all expected behavior

Another option would be to wrap the Width/Height declaration in a setTimeout in order to let the browser finish it's unusually parsing

```
setTimeout(function(){
    const WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
    const HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
},0);
```

If this doesn't work you need to tether your iPad to a mac and debug the browser. I don't think your WIDTH and HEIGHT are what you expect them to be at the time of declaration.