# window.innerWidth is not being set

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I'm currently porting https://github.com/brunolemos/simplified-twitter to Safari.

I'm injecting this content script into Twitter:

```js
function update(win = window) {
  window.innerWidth = Math.min(win.outerWidth, 800)
  document.body.style.paddingLeft = win.innerWidth >= 800 ? '176px' : null
}

function triggerUpdate() {
  setTimeout(() => window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')), 1)
}

window.onresize = e => update(e.target || window)
window.onload = triggerUpdate
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', triggerUpdate)

triggerUpdate()
```

The function update() works, since when I check `document.body.style.paddingLeft` in the console, it says 176px.

But when I check `window.innerWidth` it tells me 1680px instead of 800px.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629969/ios-return-bad-value-for-window-innerheight-width

Comment: might be useful https://github.com/sixfoot1/Resizer

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function update() {
  document.body.style.paddingLeft = window.outerWidth >= 800 ? '176px' : null
}

function triggerUpdate() {
  setTimeout(() => window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')), 1)
}

window.onresize = update
window.onload = triggerUpdate
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', triggerUpdate)

triggerUpdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

This was kind of tricky.
Apparently when I'm modifying window, I'm not actually modifying the window of twitter.com

To do that, I would need to inject a  tag into twitter.com.

To do this, I can create a second script (call it inject.js), add it to the Content Scripts Array in the Info.plist and write this in it:

```
const script = document.createElement('script')
script.src = safari.extension.baseURI + "script.js"
document.documentElement.appendChild(script)
```

This will create a new script element, assign the URI to the injected script to its src attribute and append it to the document.